# SQL Exists to search a freetext

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the DDL below:

```
create table Door_Supervisors (DID int not null, Name varchar(30))
create table general_log (id int not null, Notes varchar(100))
INSERT INTO Door_Supervisors values (1,'ian')
INSERT INTO Door_Supervisors values (2,'Mark')
INSERT INTO General_Log values (1, 'This is a Test 1127678 DID: 000001 DId: 000010')
```

I want to return all Door Supervisors that are mentioned in General_Log i.e. 1 is mentioned (as 000001).  256 would be: 000256.  In the case of the data above, the statement should return DID1 and not DID2.  I believe I can use an EXISTS statement.  Some variation of this:

> SELECT Door_Supervisors.* FROM Door_Supervisors WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT
>   * FROM General_Log WHERE Notes LIKE '%DID: ' + RIGHT('000000' + Door_Supervisors.DID,6) + '%')

Comment: What's wrong with your existing code? You might need to convert front `int` to `varchar()` in your comparison.

Comment: I don't know how to join Door Supervisor with General_Log because there is no common ID.

Comment: You need to clarify what you want your output to look like. Consider including more sample data too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Ds.* 
FROM Door_Supervisors ds
JOIN General_log gl on CAST(substring(Notes,6,9) as Int)=ds.did
```

SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fb4c/1

Note that this code assumes the structured text in **Notes** is consistent...

Comment: Thanks.  I have updated my question.  I did not state that the content of General_Log.Notes is free text i.e. it can contain any information, but will always contain DID: 000001 for door supervisor 1, 000002 for door supervisor 2, 000100 for door supervisor 100 etc.

Comment: Your example has two occurrences of DID: ???   Does this mean you could possibly expect two records from a single note field?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this -

```
SELECT ds.DID, ds.[Name]
FROM  Door_Supervisors ds
INNER JOIN general_log gl ON  ds.DID = CAST(reverse(left(reverse(gl.notes), charindex(':',reverse(gl.notes), 1) - 1)) AS INT)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/313a6/2/0)

Comment: Thanks.  I have updated my question.  I did not state that the content of General_Log.Notes is free text i.e. it can contain any information, but will always contain DID: 000001 for door supervisor 1, 000002 for door supervisor 2, 000100 for door supervisor 100 etc.

Comment: This works for any text. Just separator between text and door supervisor should be `:`.

Comment: I have added more info to the question. There can be many door supervisors referenced in the notes free text.

Comment: Do you have fixed format for defining multiple door supervisor?

Answer (score 0):

Because your requirements aren't entirely clear I've made some assumptions about what you want.

- You want to return the values from both tables.
- Where there's a pattern of 6 numbers (`123456`) in the notes you want to join this to the corresponding door supervisor.

-

```
SELECT *
FROM   Door_Supervisors
 INNER
  JOIN General_Log
    ON General_Log.Notes LIKE '%' + Right('000000', Cast(Door_Supervisors.DID as varchar(6)), 6) + '%'
WHERE  General_Log.Notes LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question. I did not state that the content of General_Log.Notes is free text i.e. it can contain any information, but will always contain DID: 000001 for door supervisor 1, 000002 for door supervisor 2, 000100 for door supervisor 100 etc